# Selection done in one iteration in lwc, is reflecting in every other iteration

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I have a requirement where I have to create Opportunity line Item on click of custom button(LWC) on Opportunity.
This component have multiple picklist fields. It works something like below
Field "Product Selection" contains values Red,White, Black
On selection of value in Field "Product Selection" ex Red , "Field PLCC Specification" is visible with values as (Red1, Red2, Red3)
On selection of value in Field "Product Selection" ex Black , "CO-brand Specifications / Tiers" is visible with values as (Black1, Black2)
There is a button named as "Add Product" on click of button new row is added where Field A is visible with values Red,White, Black and then again based on value in Field A other picklist fields are visible
but what is happening here is if i am changing value in Row 1 ,  values are getting change in Row2.Below is my code.

```
<template>
    <template if:true={showSpinner}>
        <div class="customSpinner">
            <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="large" style="position: fixed;"></lightning-spinner>
        </div>
    </template>
    <div class="slds-text-align_right">
        <lightning-button variant="Neutral" label="Manage Discovery" title="Manage Discovery" onclick={showModalHandler}></lightning-button>
     </div>
     <template if:true={showModal}>
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large"
        aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <header class="slds-modal__header">
                <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Manage Discovery</h2>
            </header>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium modal-content-min-height" id="modal-content-id-1">
        <lightning-card title={valueText}>
            <div class="slds-p-horizontal_medium">
                <template for:each={itemList} for:item="item" for:index="index">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters" key={item.Id}>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-5 slds-m-bottom_medium">
                        <lightning-combobox 
                        class="validValue specification customCombobox"
                        name="progress" 
                        data-indexnum={index}
                        label="Product Selection" 
                        value={value}
                        placeholder="Select the Product" 
                        options={eventOptions} 
                        onchange={handleEventMgrChange}
                        required>
                    </lightning-combobox>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-5 slds-m-bottom_medium">
                <template if:true={isPLCC}>
                   
                           <lightning-combobox
                              data-id="plccspecification"
                              class="validValue specification customCombobox slds-hide"
                              name="specification"
                              data-indexnum={index}
                              label="PLCC Specification"
                              value={value}
                              options={options}
                              onchange={handlePlccSpecification}
                              required>
                           </lightning-combobox>
                </template>
                <template if:true={isCoBrand}>
                           <lightning-combobox
                              data-id="cobrandspecification"
                              class="validValue specification customCombobox slds-hide"
                              name="cobrandspecification"
                              data-indexnum={index}
                              label="CO-brand Specifications / Tiers"
                              value={value}
                              options={options}
                              onchange={handleCoBrandSpecifications}
                              required>
                           </lightning-combobox>
                </template>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-5 slds-m-bottom_medium">
                
                        <lightning-combobox
                           data-id="masterCardSpecs"
                           class="validValue specification customCombobox slds-hide"
                           name="masterCardSpecs"
                           data-indexnum={index}
                           label="Mastercard Specs"
                           value={value}
                           options={options}
                           onchange={handleMasterCardSpecs}
                           required>
                        </lightning-combobox>
                
                        <lightning-combobox
                           data-id="visaSpecs"
                           class="validValue specification customCombobox slds-hide"
                           name="visaSpecs"
                           data-indexnum={index}
                           label="Visa Specs"
                           value={value}
                           options={options}
                           onchange={handleVisaSpecsChanges}
                           required>
                        </lightning-combobox>
               
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-5 slds-m-bottom_medium">
                
                        <lightning-combobox
                           data-id="visaStandard"
                           class="validValue specification customCombobox slds-hide"
                           name="visaStandard"
                           data-indexnum={index}
                           label="Visa Standard Specs"
                           value={value}
                           options={options}
                           onchange={handleVisaStandardChanges}
                           required>
                        </lightning-combobox>
            
                        <lightning-combobox
                           data-id="visaSignature"
                           class="validValue specification customCombobox slds-hide"
                           name="visaSignature"
                           data-indexnum={index}
                           label="Visa Signature Specs"
                           value={value}
                           options={options}
                           onchange={handleVisaSignatureChanges}
                           required>
                        </lightning-combobox>
                
                        <lightning-combobox
                           data-id="masterStandard"
                           class="validValue specification customCombobox slds-hide"
                           name="masterStandard"
                           data-indexnum={index}
                           label="Master Standard Specs"
                           value={value}
                           options={options}
                           onchange={handleMasterStandardChanges}
                           required>
                        </lightning-combobox>
               
                        <lightning-combobox
                           data-id="masterWorld"
                           class="validValue specification customCombobox slds-hide"
                           name="masterWorld"
                           data-indexnum={index}
                           label="Master World Specs"
                           value={value}
                           options={options}
                           onchange={handlemasterWorldChanges}
                           required>
                        </lightning-combobox>
               
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-5 slds-m-bottom_medium">
                <lightning-icon icon-name="action:delete" access-key={item.id} id={index}
                                alternative-text="Delete Row" size="small" title="Delete Row" onclick={removeRow}>
                            </lightning-icon>
            </div>
        </div>
        </template>
    </div>
        </lightning-card>
        </div>
         <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" data-id="saveButtonId" onclick={saveOppLineItem}>Save</button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" data-id="addProductId" onclick={addProduct}>Add Product</button>
        </footer>
    </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </template>
</template>`enter code here`
JS
    import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from "lwc";
import getProducts from "@salesforce/apex/NewOpportunityLineItem.getProducts";
import getSpecifications from "@salesforce/apex/NewOpportunityLineItem.getSpecifications";
import ceateOpportunityLineItem from "@salesforce/apex/NewOpportunityLineItem.ceateOpportunityLineItem";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";

export default class OpportunityLineItemCreation extends LightningElement {
  @track prodId;
  @api recordId;
  valueText = "Select Product";
  @track productData; //contain product object data for 4 products
  keyIndex = 0;
  @track itemList = [
    {
      id: 0,
    },
  ];
  //  Array of picklist values  //
  @track returnOptions = [];
  @track storeNameId = [];
  @track plccOptions = [];
  @track coBrandOptions = [];
  @track mCardSpecsOptions = [];
  @track visaSpecsOptions = [];
  @track mcStandardSpecsOptions = [];
  @track mcWordSpecsOptions = [];
  @track vStandardSpecsOptions = [];
  @track vSignatureSpecsOptions = [];
  @track parameterObjectWrapper = [];
  // Contains selected picklist value //
  @track storevalue = "";
  @track plccValue = "";
  @track coBrandValue = "";
  @track mcSpecsValue = "";
  @track mcStandardSpecsValue = "";
  @track mcWordSpecsValue = "";
  @track vSpecsValue = "";
  @track vStandardSpecsValue = "";
  @track vSignatureSpecsValue = "";
  // BOOLEAN //
  showSpinner = false;
  showModal = false;
  @track isPLCC = true;
  @track isCoBrand = true;
  @track isMasterCard = true;
  @track isVisa = true;
  @track isVisaStandard = true;
  @track isMasterStandard = true;
  @track isVisaSignature = true;
  @track isMasterWorld = true;
  allValid = false;
  uniqueCombo = false;
  @wire(getProducts)
  productList;

  get eventOptions() {
    if (this.productList.data) {
      this.productList.data.forEach((ele) => {
        this.returnOptions.push({ label: ele.Name, value: ele.Name });
        this.storeNameId.push({ label: ele.Name, value: ele.Id });
      });
    }
    return this.returnOptions;
  }
  /*get hasResults() {
    return this.eventsList.data.length > 0;
  }*/
  /*Modal toggle start*/
  showModalHandler() {
    //this.returnOptions = [];
    this.showModal = true;
  }
  closeModal() {
    // to close modal window set 'showModal' track value as false
    this.showModal = false;
  }
  /*Modal toggle End*/

  saveOppLineItem() {
    this.parameterObjectWrapper = [];
    //for (var i = 0; i < this.itemList.length; i++) {
      this.validate();
      this.showSpinner = true;
      //if (this.allValid) {
        this.template.querySelector('data-id').forEach(element => {
          this.parameterObjectWrapper.push({
            productName: this.storevalue,
            selProductId: this.prodId,
            plccSpecifications: this.plccValue,
            coBrandTiers: this.coBrandValue,
            mcSpecs: this.mcSpecsValue,
            mcStandardSpecs: this.mcStandardSpecsValue,
            mcWordSpecs: this.mcWordSpecsValue,
            vSpecs: this.vSpecsValue,
            vStandardSpecs: this.vStandardSpecsValue,
            vSignatureSpecs: this.vSignatureSpecsValue,
          });
      });
        
      //}
    //}
    alert(
      "parameterObjectWrapper==" + JSON.stringify(this.parameterObjectWrapper)
    );
    ceateOpportunityLineItem({
      oppLineItemRecList: this.parameterObjectWrapper,
      oppId: this.recordId,
    }).then(() => {
      const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        message: "Opportunity Line item Created",
        variant: "success",
      });
      //);
      this.dispatchEvent(evt);
      this.showSpinner = false;
    });
  }

  addProduct() {
    var newItemList = [];
    newItemList = this.itemList;
    this.itemList = [];
    this.validate();
    //if (this.allValid) {
      ++this.keyIndex;
      var newItem = [{ id: this.keyIndex }];
      this.itemList = newItemList.concat(newItem);
    //}
  }
  removeRow(event) {
    if (this.itemList.length >= 0) {
      this.itemList = this.itemList.filter(function (element) {
        return parseInt(element.id) !== parseInt(event.target.accessKey);
      });
    }
  }
  ////Validate Opportunity Line Item////
  validate() {
    this.allValid = [...this.template.querySelectorAll(".validValue")].reduce(
      (validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
        inputCmp.reportValidity();
        return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
      },
      true
    );
    /*if (this.storevalue == "PLCC" || this.storevalue == "Commercial PLCC") {
              if(){

              }
            }else if (
              this.storevalue == "Co-brand" ||
              this.storevalue == "Commercial Co-brand"
            ) {
            }*/
  }
  ///////// Handle Change Start/////////
  handleEventMgrChange(event) {
    var indexnumber = event.target.dataset.indexnum;
    let iterationindex = this.template.querySelector(
      '[data-indexnum="' + indexnumber + '"]'
    );
    this.storevalue = event.target.value;
    this.valueText = "Product Selected";
    this.isVisaStandard = false;
    this.isMasterStandard = false;
    this.isVisaSignature = false;
    this.isMasterWorld = false;
    this.isMasterCard = false;
    this.isVisa = false;
    this.plccOptions = [];
    var productId = "";
    var plccOptionArray = [];
    var coBrandOptionArray = [];
    this.coBrandOptions = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.storeNameId.length; i++) {
      if (this.storeNameId[i].label === this.storevalue) {
        productId = this.storeNameId[i].value;
        this.prodId = productId;
      }
    }
    if (productId) {
      getSpecifications({ selProductId: productId })
        .then((result) => {
          this.productData = result;
          if (
            this.storevalue == "PLCC" ||
            this.storevalue == "Commercial PLCC"
          ) {
            alert("plccjj");

            plccOptionArray =
              this.productData.PLCC_Specifications__c.split(";");
            for (var i = 0; i < plccOptionArray.length; i++) {
              this.plccOptions.push({
                label: plccOptionArray[i],
                value: plccOptionArray[i],
              });
            }

            this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id="plccspecification"]')
              .forEach((element) => {
                if (
                  element.dataset.id == "plccspecification" &&
                  element.dataset.indexnum == indexnumber
                ) {
                  element.className = "validValue specification customCombobox";
                  element.options = this.plccOptions;
                }
              });
          } else if (
            this.storevalue == "Co-brand" ||
            this.storevalue == "Commercial Co-brand"
          ) {
            alert("co");
            coBrandOptionArray =
              this.productData.CObrand_Specifications_Tiers__c.split(";");
            for (var i = 0; i < coBrandOptionArray.length; i++) {
              this.coBrandOptions.push({
                label: coBrandOptionArray[i],
                value: coBrandOptionArray[i],
              });
            }

            this.template
              .querySelectorAll('[data-id="cobrandspecification"]')
              .forEach((element) => {
                if (
                  element.dataset.id == "cobrandspecification" &&
                  element.dataset.indexnum == indexnumber
                ) {
                  element.className = "validValue specification customCombobox";
                  element.options = this.coBrandOptions;
                }
              });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.error = error;
        });
    }
    // }
  }

  handlePlccSpecification(event) {
    this.plccValue = event.target.value;
    this.isVisaStandard = false;
    this.isMasterStandard = false;
    this.isVisaSignature = false;
    this.isMasterWorld = false;
  }
  handleCoBrandSpecifications(event) {
    var indexnumber = event.target.dataset.indexnum;
    this.isMasterCard = false;
    this.isVisa = false;
    this.isVisaStandard = false;
    this.isMasterStandard = false;
    this.isVisaSignature = false;
    this.isMasterWorld = false;
    this.coBrandValue = event.target.value;
    this.mCardSpecsOptions = [];
    this.visaSpecsOptions = [];
    var masterCardSpecsArray = [];
    var visaSpecArray = [];
    if (this.coBrandValue == "MasterCard") {
      masterCardSpecsArray = this.productData.Mastercard_Specs__c.split(";");
      for (var i = 0; i < masterCardSpecsArray.length; i++) {
        this.mCardSpecsOptions.push({
          label: masterCardSpecsArray[i],
          value: masterCardSpecsArray[i],
        });
      }
      this.template
        .querySelectorAll('[data-id="masterCardSpecs"]')
        .forEach((element) => {
          if (
            element.dataset.id == "masterCardSpecs" &&
            element.dataset.indexnum == indexnumber
          ) {
            element.className = "validValue specification customCombobox";
            element.options = this.mCardSpecsOptions;
          }
        });
    } else if (this.coBrandValue == "Visa") {
      visaSpecArray = this.productData.Visa_Specs__c.split(";");
      for (var i = 0; i < visaSpecArray.length; i++) {
        this.visaSpecsOptions.push({
          label: visaSpecArray[i],
          value: visaSpecArray[i],
        });
      }
      this.template
        .querySelectorAll('[data-id="visaSpecs"]')
        .forEach((element) => {
          if (
            element.dataset.id == "visaSpecs" &&
            element.dataset.indexnum == indexnumber
          ) {
            element.className = "validValue specification customCombobox";
            element.options = this.visaSpecsOptions;
          }
        });
    }
  }
  handleMasterCardSpecs(event) {
    var indexnumber = event.target.dataset.indexnum;
    var iterationindex = this.template.querySelector(
      '[data-indexnum="' + indexnumber + '"]'
    );
    //if (indexnumber == iterationindex.dataset.indexnum) {
      this.isMasterStandard = false;
      this.isMasterWorld = false;
      this.isVisaStandard = false;
      this.isVisaSignature = false;
      this.mcSpecsValue = event.target.value;
      this.mcStandardSpecsOptions = [];
      this.mcWordSpecsOptions = [];
      var mcStandardSpecsArray = [];
      var mcWordSpecsArray = [];
      if (this.mcSpecsValue == "Standard") {
        mcStandardSpecsArray =
          this.productData.Mastercard_Standard_Specs__c.split(";");
        for (var i = 0; i < mcStandardSpecsArray.length; i++) {
          this.mcStandardSpecsOptions.push({
            label: mcStandardSpecsArray[i],
            value: mcStandardSpecsArray[i],
          });
        }
        this.template
          .querySelectorAll('[data-id="masterStandard"]')
          .forEach((element) => {
            if (
              element.dataset.id == "masterStandard" &&
              element.dataset.indexnum == indexnumber
            ) {
              element.className = "validValue specification customCombobox";
              element.options = this.mcStandardSpecsOptions;
            }
          });
      } else if (this.mcSpecsValue == "World") {
        mcWordSpecsArray = this.productData.MasterCard_Word_Specs__c.split(";");
        for (var i = 0; i < mcWordSpecsArray.length; i++) {
          this.mcWordSpecsOptions.push({
            label: mcWordSpecsArray[i],
            value: mcWordSpecsArray[i],
          });
        }
        this.template
          .querySelectorAll('[data-id="masterWorld"]')
          .forEach((element) => {
            if (
              element.dataset.id == "masterWorld" &&
              element.dataset.indexnum == indexnumber
            ) {
              element.className = "validValue specification customCombobox";
              element.options = this.mcWordSpecsOptions;
            }
          });
      }
    //}
  }
  handleVisaSpecsChanges(event) {
    var indexnumber = event.target.dataset.indexnum;
    var iterationindex = this.template.querySelector(
      '[data-indexnum="' + indexnumber + '"]'
    );
    //if (indexnumber == iterationindex.dataset.indexnum) {
      this.isVisaStandard = false;
      this.isVisaSignature = false;
      this.isMasterStandard = false;
      this.isMasterWorld = false;
      this.vSpecsValue = event.target.value;
      this.vStandardSpecsOptions = [];
      this.vSignatureSpecsOptions = [];
      var vStandardSpecsArray = [];
      var vSignatureSpecsArray = [];
      if (this.vSpecsValue == "Standard") {
        vStandardSpecsArray =
          this.productData.Visa_Standard_Specs__c.split(";");
        for (var i = 0; i < vStandardSpecsArray.length; i++) {
          this.vStandardSpecsOptions.push({
            label: vStandardSpecsArray[i],
            value: vStandardSpecsArray[i],
          });
        }
        this.template
          .querySelectorAll('[data-id="visaStandard"]')
          .forEach((element) => {
            if (
              element.dataset.id == "visaStandard" &&
              element.dataset.indexnum == indexnumber
            ) {
              element.className = "validValue specification customCombobox";
              element.options = this.vStandardSpecsOptions;
            }
          });
      } else if (this.vSpecsValue == "Signature") {
        vSignatureSpecsArray =
          this.productData.Visa_Signature_Specs__c.split(";");
        for (var i = 0; i < vSignatureSpecsArray.length; i++) {
          this.vSignatureSpecsOptions.push({
            label: vSignatureSpecsArray[i],
            value: vSignatureSpecsArray[i],
          });
        }
        this.template
          .querySelectorAll('[data-id="visaSignature"]')
          .forEach((element) => {
            if (
              element.dataset.id == "visaSignature" &&
              element.dataset.indexnum == indexnumber
            ) {
              element.className = "validValue specification customCombobox";
              element.options = this.vSignatureSpecsOptions;
            }
          });
      }
    //}
  }
  handleVisaStandardChanges(event) {
    this.vStandardSpecsValue = event.target.value;
  }
  handleVisaSignatureChanges(event) {
    this.vSignatureSpecsValue = event.target.value;
  }
  handleMasterStandardChanges(event) {
    this.mcStandardSpecsValue = event.target.value;
  }
  handlemasterWorldChanges(event) {
    this.mcWordSpecsValue = event.target.value;
  }
  ///////// Handle Change End/////////

  
}
```

No my next issue is how to add values of each row in wrapper for each iteration and on click of save all rows must be saved

Comment: In addition to answer below, you can also move all the combo boxes inside the iteration into a separate component and let that component manage the state for all combo boxes for each iteration. This is something similar to an expense manager app of Salesforce.

Answer (score 3):

You're binding the various attributes, e.g. `value={plccValue}` such that they're all pointing to the same variable, but you should be pointing to different elements in an Array, e.g. `value={item.plccValue}`. You need to make sure you're pointing all your variables to the right place.

Comment: I have followed another approach , updating code in main question